# My Discord bot keeps getting an error message

Tags: discord.js

It says this in the logs, and I do not know why. It just randomly appeared when I went onto glitch.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '/app/server/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: I think this is a problem package.json, the `'/app/server/server.js'` file can't be found and its trying to run it in your package.json

Comment: @Nodejs-nerd where would I put that in?

Comment: Whats in your package.json file?

Comment: ```{
  "name": "IhsBot",
  "version": "1.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w server/server.js server/server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "discord": "^0.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
}```